# Jenkins build not able to generate sources

Tags: jenkins, build, maven-3

I'm having some trouble with my jenkins build - I'm trying to generate some sources based on several json files. No problem on my lokalhost, but my Jenkins build always fails with this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.23:generate (DriversGeneration) on project DKVGatewayRestClient: Execution DriversGeneration of goal org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin:0.4.23:generate failed: Unrecognised URI, can't resolve this: http://gateway-int.dkv-euroservice.com/metadatastore/1.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mds/com/dkv/shared/drivers/getCardList.json: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
```

Basically it says that `http://gateway-int.dkv-euroservice.com/metadatastore/1.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mds/com/dkv/shared/drivers/getCardList.json` is not a valid URI, but this definatly is not the case. As said, my localhost can work with this URI without any problems - browser and maven build work exactly as expected. Even using requesting this URL via curl on my Jenkins server works perfectly fine. Just the Jenkins build constantly fails. Have already restartet Jenkins but no difference ...

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance and regards. Sebastian